# Chrome Dev Tools on Linux: Can't Open Stacktrace Links

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

I'm on Linux (Mint) and using the Chrome Developer Tools.  Whenever I click on a file link in a stack trace (from an error, warning, etc.) ... for instance if I click on `layout.js` in ...

```
at FrontPage (webpack-internal:///./src/components/layout.js:46:11)
```

... Chrome then tries to open the link to:

```
webpack-internal:///./src/components/layout.js
```

Previously that would just show me the file in the Dev Tools' "Sources" tab ... but now it instead opens a prompt from xdg-open, saying "A website wants to open this application."

If I open it, I'm stuck on an empty tab for `webpack-internal:///./src/components/layout.js`.  If I cancel, nothing happens.

Does anyone know how I can get it to go back to opening such links within the Dev Tools Sources tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Chrome developer explained [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1453907)

> The problem here is that part of the `Error.stack` content contains a stack trace from the Node.js server, while you are debugging the React client (in the browser).

> Our recommendation is to open a bug against next.js - they should not provide broken links to DevTools.

Comment: Is there an open issue on Github?

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/54150

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact solution, but I can suggest you one when I come across similar situation.
You can try adding your source code folder to chrome's dev tools workspace tab which is under sources tab.
You can refer to [Chrome Workspace Guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/settings/workspace/).
I am also attaching a screenshot from my desktop to help you figure out.
Hope it will help.
Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't really a solution, as it doesn't restore the old behavior, and won't let me debug other (remote) sites.

Comment: Also, I just tried it anyway and ... unfortunately it didn't help, even for my local files :(

Comment: I am sorry, you are right. It's really annoying. Even I need it. In case if I find any solution, I will definitely post it here. Thanks :)